# UI got a little stuck since fetching a photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, animation, smoothing

Now I'm using this code, with a little modification:

```
if (self._photoPath && !self._photo) {
        dispatch_queue_t bg_thread = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourcompany.bg_thread", NULL);
        dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
        dispatch_async(bg_thread,^{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self._photoPath];
            if(data != nil) {
                dispatch_async(main_queue,^{ 
                    self._photo = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    [self.photoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photoButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

As you can see, in fact after I get that photo I want set it immediately to my "photoButton",
but now, UI got smoothed, but my photoButton's appearance is always black...

What should I do next?

_______________________Updated___________________

I have 2 viewControllers, A and B.
A is the root viewController, and B is A's child viewController.
In B, there is a button for calling the camera to take a photo.

After user took a photo, the photo's appearance becomes that photo.

When I push a new B (with no photo) from A,
things goes smoothly.
But when there is an old B with a photo in it,
the animation gets a little stuck, caused by the following code I guess:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    if (self._photoPath && !self._photo) {
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self._photoPath];
            if(data != nil)
                self._photo = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }
    [super viewWillApear];
}
```

But I do need to get that photo before the view is displayed since I need to set that photo to my photoButton's background.

So, is there a way to avoid sticking the view's animation? Because it really result in bad user experience.

Comment: You should add a tag for the language and GUI toolkit you are using, so people knowledgeable in those subjects will notice the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching the photo in a backgroudn thread (I'm using GCD here):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    if (self._photoPath && !self._photo) {
      dispatch_queue_t bg_thread = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourcompany.bg_thread", NULL);
      dispatch_queue_t main_queue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
      dispatch_async(bg_thread,^{
          NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self._photoPath];
          if(data != nil) {
            dispatch_async(main_queue,^{ self._photo = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; });
          }
      });
    }
    [super viewWillApear];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I never used a background thread, I have not even used any extra and manual thread except simple UIAnimation. This is an iPhone app and all my properties are nonatomic, is there anything I should pay attension when usin your code? Thanks again!

Comment: Just try this piece of code :) It should work and help to prevent your UI from lagging.

Comment: By the way, I guess I'm using GDB in my project, does it make any difference about your GCD?

Comment: GCD = Grand central dispatch, which is used for multi-threading …

Comment: Thanks! UI does not lag anymore, but there's a new problem, I will add it above immediately.

Comment: Naah, open a new question for that ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445859/a-follow-up-q-for-avoid-ui-getting-lagged-ios